# Id the device when submitting web forms

Tags: javascript, php

So I'm trying to figure out a way the source code can extract an ID from the device that's submitting the form.

I'm trying to build a web app, that will be used by say, 10 people at most.
My goal is to prevent one person from entering everyone's data on web form.

Currently I'm using Php, to record entries into the Mysql Database.
Geo Location on web on the client to record address.

Comment: What kind of ID are you talking about?

Comment: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` will give you the an IP from each user... not sure if that's what you mean by "id"

Comment: I haven't tried anything so far. ID: mac address or Ip

Comment: Try something, edit the question with what you've done and the code you've used.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm new at this, I haven't coded or tried anything as of this point. I like the IP code Configure recommended up top. What other methods could one use to ID users?

Comment: @Confiqure :  
I think that would work, everyone IP address is different. Therefore, If I get 10 forms and they all have the same IP something is not right